# jQuery show() method resets "li" entries to display:block

Tags: jquery

I have a relatively simple page that has a couple of LI entries that I want to be able to show on click.  The idea is to simulate PowerPoints logic where groups of elements appear when you click on the page.

In the "click()" handler for the parent "div" element I have:

```
$(function() {
    var currentReveal;
    var currentGroup = 1;

    currentReveal = $("[class*=Revealed]").hide().length;
    $("div").click(function() {
    if (currentReveal != 0) {
        var revealedElements = $("[class*=Revealed]").filter("[revealgroup='" +
                                 currentGroup + "']");
        $(revealedElements).show("normal");
        currentGroup += 1;
        currentReveal -= revealedElements.length;
    }
});
```

The HTML that this is acting on is:

```
    <div class="Body">
    <ul>

    <li>Lorem Ipsus</li>
    <ul>
        <li class="RevealedList" revealgroup="1" >Lorem Ipsus:</li>
        <ul class="Revealed" revealgroup="1">
            <li>Lorem Ipsus.</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsus.</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="RevealedList" revealgroup="1">Lorem Ipsus</li>
     </ul>
     </div>
```

Unfortunately when the show() command finishes executing, the "li" entry has a style of "display:block" and not a style of "display:list-item" (verified with firebug and IE).  I know I can trivially work around this problem (by updating the code to fix the style after the "show()" method has completed), but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hmmm... I just looked at jQuerys bug database and found: http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5130 which implies that this might be a jQuery bug.

Comment: Just updated the ticket with a fix: http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5130#comment:3

Comment: Thank you petersendidit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `.hide()`, your `li` elements get `display:hide`, so `.show()` sets them to `display:block` because the previous `display` property value has been lost. So you have two alternatives:

- Remove *Revealed*-like classes from the `li` and put them in the `ul` or other container element that is able to get `display` set to `block` or
- Instead of `.show()`, try using something like `.css({display:'list-item'})`

I'd probably go with the second one.

If you want to achieve a `.show("normal")`-like effect, you can do something like

```
// assume the following var
var yourstuff = $(/* the stuff you're hiding */);

// instead of just calling .hide(), store width and height first
yourstuff.each(function() {
  $(this).data('orig_w',$(this).width())
         .data('orig_h',$(this).height())
}).hide()

// then, instead of resetting 'display', animate the stuff
yourstuff.css({display:'list-item', overflow: 'hidden', width:0, height: 0;})
  .animate({width: yourstuff.data('orig_w'), height: yourstuff.data('orig_h')},
     "normal", //speed
     "linear", //easing
     function() { // in the end, reset 'overflow' to show the bullet
       yourstuff.css('overflow', 'none');
     })
```

I hope the above snippet to be enough to give you an idea of what to do.

Comment: IIRC, this is a known bug and should be fixed in one of the next versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this a few years old, but I encountered this today:

jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()` **do restore the proper display-property** of the `<li>` element, but **only when not animating it**.

I.e., just calling `.hide()` and `.show()` will restore to `list-item`.

But calling `.show(250)` will restore to `block`.

Answer (score 1):

@Larry & @Miguel:

I've just tested this with a simple script that `hide()`s and `show()`s my `<li>`s, and they were set back to "list-item". Actually, if you look at jQuery's source code, on the `show()` method, you will see:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
show: function(speed,callback){
/* ... */
var old = jQuery.data(this[i], "olddisplay");
/* ... */
jQuery.data(this[i], "olddisplay", display);
```

And if you look at the `hide()` method, you will that it actually saves the value o `display` before setting it to none:

```
var old = jQuery.data(this[i], "olddisplay");
if ( !old && old !== "none" )
    jQuery.data(this[i], "olddisplay", jQuery.css(this[i], "display"));
```

The code I used to test it with Firebug:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("li").click(function() {
        $("li").hide();
        $("li").show();})
    });
</script>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>foo</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Are you sure you can confirm the problem you are talking about? Maybe there's something important I didn't get, or that you didn't tell us.

Good luck!

Comment: The display is being set to "block" in show - the code "if ( display === "none" ) display = "block"; is executing.  I believe that the code at this location should be the code you described above (jQuery.data(this...).

Comment: You could try setting some breakpoints on jQuery to see exactly what is going on. Try that! It is rather interesting.

Comment: @Larry: actually that line you highlighted is unimportant. The display style of the `li` elements in the code I've shown you is set about 10 lines before what you hightlighted: `var old = jQuery.data(this[i], "olddisplay"); this[i].style.display = old || "";` After this, IF it couldn't reset the display to the `olddisplay` value, THEN it will set it to block, as the code you've highlighted. Not in the case of the code I've shown you...

Comment: Bruno: I've put breakpoints in the code you which resets the style back to the old value.  It doesn't get executed.  I don't know why it doesn't get executed but it doesn't.  For your example, you might try issueing the call to hide() in the ready handler and then the show() in the click handler.  You're also not using an animation on your call to show() - try it with "show(normal)" (with a timeout jQuery executes a totally different path).

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, at least your problem is solved and we know what caused it! God luck!